# Como pluralizar “1” e “1º”?

Tags: número-gramatical, números

Em inglês, sei que é correto escrever *1's* para pluralizar *1*, como em «In binary you write in 1's and 0's» («Em binário, escreve-se em 1's e 0's»), mas não sei se é correto pluralizar dessa forma nem se se deve fazer isso em português.

Então pergunto: como deve, se deve, pluralizar *1* e *1º*?

Isto é, como pluralizar, se deve, os números em «toda soma com um ou mais **0**, os seus **0** são descartáveis» e em «Tenho várias **1ª** coisas na lista de compras».

Comment: Sim, Schilive, acho que está ótimo :)

Comment: Isso: Tenho várias 1ª coisas não é português...em primeira posição

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um ponto é unânime (veja, e.g., [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/siglas-no-plural/15596) e [aqui](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1570)): não se usa o "apóstrofo + s" para indicar plural. Na língua inglesa raramente ele é aceitável (essencialmente apenas para o plural de letras minúsculas) e em português o mecanismo simplesmente não existe.

O plural do ordinal "1º" é fácil, pois ele [flexiona](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/abreviaturas-de-ordinais-no-plural/32084) da maneira usual:

> o 1ᵒ colocado, os 1ᵒˢ colocados, a 1ᵃ a chegar, as 1ᵃˢ da fila, os 2ᵒˢ colocados, as 3ᵃˢ nas listas, etc.

No entanto, me parece uma abreviação deselegante para o ordinal como adjetivo, como no exemplo da pergunta (que ficaria "Tenho várias 1ᵃˢ coisas na lista de compras"), embora eu não encontre fonte que coloque como incorreto.

(Não confundir com o símbolo para grau=1/360 da circunferência que, por se tratar de unidade de medida, não flexiona: "1°", "2°", etc.)

Já o "1" é um símbolo, não uma palavra, o que significa que qualquer tentativa de pluralizá-lo pode suscitar discussões. Quando escrito por extenso, seu plural [costuma ser aceito](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/numerais-cardinais/18782) e a situação é mais simples ("os seus zeros/uns são descartáveis"), embora alguns números, como "dez" e "seis" tenham a mesma forma no singular e no plural (ver [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/numerais-cardinais/18782) e [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/dez-com-ou-sem-plural/549)). Mas a pergunta é sobre o "1", não "um".

Símbolos [seriam](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/a-grafia-diferente-das-abreviaturas-e-dos-simbolos/2364) invariáveis:

> As abreviaturas admitem flexão em género e em número (p. ex.: eng.ᵃ; n.ᵒˢ ), enquanto os símbolos permanecem invariáveis (p. ex.: 25 L; 75 kg; 35 cm; 3 h; 30 ºC).

Mas eu remeteria à discussão sobre o plural de siglas, como em "os CDs": em que a posição prescritiva dominante, especialmente em pt-PT, é a de que o plural com 's' não é aceitável (ver [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/siglas-e-acronimos/3362), [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/plural-de-cd-rom/4164), [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/colectivos-livro-e-cd/22128) e [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/cd-rom-e-pin/14494), entre outros), contrastando fortememente com a língua em uso, especialmente em pt-BR que, há décadas, consagra o plural "CDs" (uma busca na rede revela inúmeros exemplos, como: [Folha, 1999](https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/especial/guia99/compras1.htm), [Deutsche Welle, 2004](https://www.dw.com/pt-br/os-cds-mais-vendidos/a-742194), [Contigo, 2020](https://contigo.uol.com.br/noticias/ultimas/de-metallica-a-the-beatles-7-cds-mais-procurados-no-site-da-amazon.phtml)). O que sugere a necessidade de uma flexibilização nesse ponto, uma flexibilização [já defendida](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/plural-de-estrangeirismos-unidades-e-de-siglas/15818) em 1999 pelo autor D´Silvas Filho:

> Eu actualizaria essa regra do plural das siglas para: 'as siglas normalmente não precisam de plural, mas nada impede que o tenham'. Noto que, por exemplo, as Selecções do 'Readers Digest' registam na sua revista de Maio deste ano, p. 62: « ….. CD-ROMs cheios …..». Aqui o símbolo de plural, de facto, poderia ser dispensado. Dispensado, mas não condenado, no meu ponto de vista.

Desse ponto de vista, deveria ser possível escrever o exemplo da pergunta como:

> Em binário, escreve-se em 1s e 0s.

Embora, pessoalmente, eu provavelmente optaria por uma construção como:

> Em binário, escreve-se usando (apenas) os símbolos "0" e "1".

Comment: O Ciberdúvidas não está se contradizendo, pois, ele fala que os símbolos são invariáveis, mas aceita “1ᵒˢ”? Muito obrigado, Stafusa, pela resposta! +1

Comment: Bom ponto, @Schilive. Me parece que o "1ᵒ" é considerado abreviação, não símbolo, inclusive podendo ser escrito (especialmente em pt-PT) com o ponto que abreviações costumam ter, "1.ᵒ". Outra possibilidade de não haver contradição seria a autora se referir implicitamente a um grupo de símbolos apenas, não a todos.

Comment: Stafusa, tanto https://www.normaculta.com.br/numerais-ordinais/ quanto https://www.todamateria.com.br/numeros-ordinais/ põem “1º” como abreviatura. Por mais que digam que deve conter um ponto após o algarismo indo-arábico (“1.º”), as leis brasileiras não o usam; ex.: http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/constituicao/constituicao.htm.

Comment: @Schilive Também prefiro sem o ponto, por isso escrevi meus exemplos na resposta sem eles. Uma curiosidade: no alemão os ordinais são indicados só por um ponto após o número, que naturalmente não flexiona, é bem prático.

Comment: Agora pensando, não seria mais correto «em binário, escreve-se em “1”s e “0”s»? Digo, não estamos usando 1, mas sim “1”? Não estou falando que “‘1’s” é correto por sinal, é apenas para explicar.

Comment: @Schilive Sim, ao menos conceitualmente faz sentido colocar as aspas - inclusive incluí agora um pequeno exemplo na minha resposta nesse sentido. A contrapartida é que carrega a notação de uma maneira relativamente desnecessária (uma vez que o sentido ainda está claro sem as aspas).

Comment: Sendo um chatinho de plantão novamente -- desculpa --, será que seria “há quatro 2s na equação” ou “há quatro 2 na equação”? Se eu tivesse que escolher, diria o primeiro, mas me parece invenção pluralizar desse modo, então, acho que ficaria à mercê do autor. Digo, o Juninho poderia até escrever “há quatro 1 na equação” ou “há apenas 1 ∅ porque é impossível haver 2 ∅s” no livro dele se quisesse. Parece-me ser questão de estilo, por mais que eu ache a tua proposta a melhor, até por já ter sido usado ou outros autores. Desculpa pela chatice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119817/discussion-between-stafusa-and-schilive).

Answer (score 1):

***1s*** e ***uns*** são possíveis.

de [Louis E. Frenzel Jr., Eletrônica Moderna](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/1):

> Os dados são um trem sequencial de pulsos de tensão que representam os 0s e **1s** binários, como mostra a Figura S21-1.

E "***uns***" [é plural de "um" como substantivo](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/um#Substantivo).

Comment: Alleção, obrigado pela resposta! Pelo que vi, o autor desse livro é americano, i.e., acho que o livro é traduzido. Na minha experiência e na do meu pai com livros de eletrônica, eles tendem a ter péssimas traduções, mantendo a pontuação da língua inglesa muitas das vezes.Obrigadíssimo de qualquer modo!

Answer (score 0):

O inglés não é o português.

Portanto, em português, eu usaria:

**Os valores (binários) 1 e 0** para falar de 1's and 0's.

Os valores 1 e 0 são usados em sistemas binários.

> Os números binários são utilizados pelos computadores para processar
> dados. É um sistema de numeração que, em vez de utilizar 10
> algarismos, utiliza apenas 2 (0 e 1). Veja como converter valores
> binários em decimais:... -

[binários](https://educacao.uol.com.br/disciplinas/matematica/numeros-binarios-2-conversao-para-decimais.htm)